# How to pluck a Backbone collection's attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I want to create an array of specific attribute values from a Backbone collection.

```
var days = _.select(
    this.collection.models,
    function(model) {
        return model.attributes.type === 'session';
    }
);

days = _.pluck(days, 'attributes'),
days = _.pluck(days, 'date');
```

This works, but seems inefficient. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without having to define `days` three times?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

pluck is a convenience method that wraps `map`, and `map` is available directly on the collection, which should make this easier.

assuming you are trying to get the `date` attribute out of your models, you can do this:

```
days = this.collection.map(function(model){
  return model.get('date');
});
```

your select call is also available on the collection directly, as the `filter` method.

```
days = this.collection.filter(function(model){ 
  return model.attributes.type === 'session'; 
});
```

you can chain these two together, but it helps if you define methods separately:

```
var sessionFilter = function(model){
  return model.attributes.type === 'session'; 
};
var getDate = function(model){ return model.get('date'); }

days = this.collection.filter(sessionFilter).map(getDate);
```

this should return the results your looking for... or something close to this at least :)

Comment: Thanks - Not quite the solution I was looking for but I will upvote yours for being helpful. Just found the answer on my own and will post.

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is the better one as I think of it, as it takes care of my selection/filter too. Will accept.

Answer (score 18):

I should have read the docs more carefully. In addition to the `pluck` method in underscore, backbone collections also have a `pluck` method.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-pluck

So, my solution would be

```
//Assumme 'collection' is a backbone collection
collection.pluck('date');
```

I still need to figure out how to best combine with filtering - perhaps using ideas from @Derick's answer, but this answers the meat of my own question.

Answer (score 6):

I think this could work :

```
var days =
    _( this.collection.where({ type : "session" }))
    .chain()
    .pluck("attributes")
    .pluck("date")
    .value()
```

Slightly more elegant, but still close to unreadable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Have the same question, and figured out a better solution. I might have just taken advantage of new features in underscore, since it's 2013 now :)

```
var days = _.invoke(this.collection.where({type : 'session'}), 'get', 'date');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is functionally the same as Derick's answer using [_.chain()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain)

```
var days = _(this.collection.models)
            .chain()
            .filter(function(model){return model.attributes.type === 'session';})
            .pluck('date')
            .value();
```