# How to get certain attribute from a list of models in a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have a Collection, that contains models, Each model has attributes, there is an attribute called country on each model. I want to iterate through the collection to get an array of countries. 
Each child has attributes,I am only interested in the country attribute. Tried _.pluck, _.each and _.where but unsuccessful. Any faster, quicker way to get a list?

[image: My collection]

Comment: When you say using `pluck` was unsuccessful, how so? What exactly did you try and what was the result?

Comment: var stooges = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Curly"},
  {name: "Larry"},
  {name: "Moe"}
]);

var names = stooges.pluck("name"); Pluck only plucks if the property you are plucking is listed in the collection, I have a collection that lists models and and each model has attributes that has the property I am looking for. So not sure how to get that property using pluck

Comment: that looks correct to me.  was the result of names `["Curly", "Larry", "Moe"]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone/Underscore: pluck a collection's attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587383/backbone-underscore-pluck-a-collections-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I found a variation of pluck on the backbone website. It lets you pluck an attribute from the models in the collections.

```
var stooges = new Backbone.Collection([
   {name: "Curly"},
   {name: "Larry"},
   {name: "Moe"}
]);

var names = stooges.pluck("name");
```